# Fidning average time it takes to finish a job

Tags: average

$30\%$ finish their job in $122\mathrm s$, $30\%$ finish their job in $68\mathrm s$, and $40\%$ finish their job in $190\mathrm s$. What is the average time it takes for a person to finish their job?

This is what I thought:
$$\frac{122\times\frac3{10}x + 68\times\frac3{10}x + 190\times\frac4{10}x }x = 133$$

But I feel like it was a long time ago I did something like this so I don't know if it is correct.

Comment: This is the correct approach to the problem!

Comment: Lol, this has nothing to do with division algebras!

Comment: of course you can skip the x (=number of jobs) in such calculations because it cancels out. The average value is value_1*q_1+value_2*q_2+..., where q_i is the fraction of items thtat have value value_i, that is percentage_i/100.